# References broken after overwriting them with new versions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference

My solution depends on around 100 dll's from another solution. The other solution was updated, so I got the latest version of it, built it then copied the dll's to my project overwriting the existing ones. When I did this, the references in visual studio were broken. I didn't know how to fix this other than by removing each reference and adding it back. This worked but it was very time consuming and tedious. Is there a way to add the references back that's faster than removing each one and adding them back?

Comment: This might depend on what "broken" means. Have the names changed? The paths? Something else? You can manually change the project files in a decent text editor if you just need to change paths/filenames - but make sure it's in version controll so you can roll back if it goes wrong.

Comment: No, the filenames and path are the same. I just got the new versions and overwrote the old versions and each reference in vs had the yellow diamond on it.

Comment: If your project references the dll's and you don't perform any copying then it will automatically update the references.  You're not doing it wrong but the easiest way to manage this would be to target the references from their native location and not copy them.  This way you can always update the project and the references would be updated also. Just reference the release versions so you have a testing version in debug...

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Thanks. Doing it this way does sound like it would be better and save time.